# Can't convert YYYYMMDD to date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to view software that has been installed within the last 30 days. The format of my date is `20150327`. When I try to the following condition in the `where` clause

```
and DateDiff(day,arp.InstallDate0,GetDate()) < 30
```

I receive the following error message:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

I have also tried the following and was unsuccessful:

```
CONVERT(varchar(8),arp.InstallDate0,112)
```

As well as:

```
ISDATE(CONVERT(datetime,arp.InstallDate0,112))
```

When I add `ISDATE`, it finally runs the query, but it is not showing any data and I know that there are installs within the last 30 days, so I'm thinking the date is still not being recognized.

***EDIT*** The InstallDate0 column is nvarchar.

Comment: try `where not isdate` and see what is wrong...

Comment: So `and DateDiff(day, convert(datetime, arp.InstallDate0, 112), GetDate()) < 30` does not work?

Comment: what datatype is the column 'InstallDate0'?

Comment: The InstallDate0 column is nvarchar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need a conversion format for YYYYMMDD when converting to `date`, `datetime2`, and `datetimeoffset`.  SQL Server recognizes this ISO standard format with no conversion in these cases, regardless of internationalization settings (there is one setting that affects my preferred format of YYYY-MM-DD; the documentation is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx)).  So, you could do:

```
where cast(arp.InstallDate0 as date) > dateadd(day, -30, getdate())
```

At this point:  "Shame on you for storing dates as strings."

That said, it is better (in your case) to do the comparison as strings rather than dates.  You have a good date format for this, so:

```
where arp.InstallDate0 > convert(varchar(8), dateadd(day, -30, getdate()), 112)
```

Why is this better?  With no functions on the column name, the query can take advantage of an appropriate index (if one is available).

Comment: I think it's strictly greater than, but that's a minor detail.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you! This is how SCCM stores the data for this table unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

You must use the syntax below, as the first argument for the [`CONVERT` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) is the target data type

```
CONVERT(datetime,'20150327',112)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the format using a converter to convert it to a date/or time string through conversion of its characters, then using the string to convert the numbers into a more usuable format with additional conversion

CONVERT(datetime,'20150327',112)

Answer (score 0):

You must use the syntax below:

```
WHERE
    DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT(datetime, arp.InstallDate0, 112), GetDate()) < 30
```